# If $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix, is it possible to always find a vector $x$ such that $x - x^\top = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, skew-symmetric-matrices

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a skew symmetric matrix, is it possible to always find a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x1^\top - 1x^\top = A$, where $1$ is a vector of all ones $\in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: What it the operation between $x$ and $x^\top$? Because subtraction would make no sense as the dimensions are different

Comment: Even if the difference would make sense , it would not be a matrix (except in the case $d=1$)

Comment: I cleared up the notation, does it make sense now?

Comment: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ and $x1^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, $1x^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ so I think the dimensions make sense.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): include some work. Hint:
It is always possible only for $d\le2$ (look at the rank of $\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R^{d\times d},\;x\mapsto x1^\top - 1x^\top$ and compare it with $d(d-1)/2$).

Answer (score -1):

Here I calculate this for dimension 2 only.

Since A is a skew-symmetric matrix,let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

If possible,let we can always find a vector $$x=\begin{pmatrix}  b \\ c\end{pmatrix}$$ s.t. $$x1^t-1x^t=A$$

Now , $$x^t=\begin{pmatrix}  b &c\end{pmatrix}$$

Then,$$\begin{pmatrix}  b \\ c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  1&1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}  1\\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  b &c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{pmatrix}  b & b \\ c&c\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}  b &c\\b&c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\therefore \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b-c\\ c-b & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus,if $b-c=a$ holds, only then we get such vector $x$.So,for given $A$,we know $a$.Then we have to express $a$ as the difference of two numbers,then using them, we can make the vector $x$.So,we can always find $x$.

Comment: Please don't answer questions going against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it, when you will have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); meanwhile, please only provide answers to better quality questions.

Comment: Moreover, you are not answering the question. As commented above with a hint, the answer is: "yes if *and only if* $d\le2$".